# How to reference equations using letters and numbers

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, numbering

Sometimes it is convenient to refer to a group of equations by a letter and a number. 
For example:

```
2+1   (A1)
2+4   (A2)
x^4   (B3)
x^e   (B4)
```

Placing 
`\tag{A\theequation}\label{eqn:thisone}\stepcounter{equation}}`
instead of just `\label{eqn:thisone}` works, but seems hacky (especially manually stepping the counter).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `subequations` environment provided by the `amsmath` package trivially allows you to get equations grouped by number and differentiated by letter.  For example,

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    2+1 & \\
    2+4 &
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    x^4 & \\
    x^e &
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

will give the output

```
2+1   (1a)
2+4   (1b) 

x^4   (2a)
x^e   (2b)
```

By redefining how the equation and subequation counters are displayed, you should also be able to switch the primary labeling to Alpha and the secondary to arabic if you specifically want `(A1)` and `(A2)` instead of `(1a)` and `(1b)`.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf has some explanations at page 33.

Comment: You mean section 33, page 60. Very useful document there. Thanks.

Comment: Subequations are probably what most other people people will want. In my case I wanted to keep the same counter for all the equations.
Your answer lead me to find the command 
`\renewcommand{\theequation}{A\arabic{equation}}` which does what I need.

Comment: @qbi Your link is in error now. Shouldn't it be ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf ?

Comment: @Clément your linkis in error now! I don't know the document in question; any change of a new link? Thanks :)

Comment: @SamT Try http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf  (archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20171013201217/http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf )