# Rename Equations to 14a and 14b but keep ordering

Tags: equations, numbering, labels, subequations

I have Equations `11`, `12`, `13` and so on. I want the next equations to be `14a` and `14b`, but the one after should again be `15`, i.e., keep the ordering. I know how to tag equations, but then the equation after `14b` would become `14` again. Here's a ME:

```
 \documentclass{revtex4-1}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{widetext}% I need this widetext thing. 
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
      1 = 1 
    \end{equation}  
\end{widetext}  
The above equation should have (14a) as a label. Now come the next equation which should have label 14b. And the one following that should have label (15). 
\begin{widetext}    
\begin{equation}
                  \sin x = 1 
    \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}
    \end{widetext}
Now next equations should have a label (15). 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Have you seen `subequations` environment from the package `amsmath`? I think it can help you with what you need.

Comment: Yes but the equations are far apart i.e. a lot of text in between them.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Would you please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing your situation?

Comment: @LoveLearning Just begin `subequations` before the paragraph containing equation 14a and end it after the paragraph containing equation 14b.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to reference equations using letters and numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494/5764)

Comment: I updated with a ME

Comment: OK I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Just reordering the position of the place where `\begin{subequations}` and `\end{subequations}` appear as the below example solves the problem:

```
 \documentclass{revtex4-1}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}        
        \begin{widetext}% I need this widetext thing. 
            \begin{equation}
              1 = 1 
            \end{equation}  
        \end{widetext}  
    The above equation should have (14a) as a label. Now come the next equation
 which should have label 14b. And the one following that should have label (15). 
        \begin{widetext}    
            \begin{equation}
                 \sin x = 1 
            \end{equation}
        \end{widetext}
    \end{subequations} 
    Now next equation **will** have a label (15). :D  
    \end{document}
```