# Regarding equation number

Tags: equations, numbering

I have two equations like

```
\begin{equation}
a
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b
\end{equation}
```

I need the equations to be numbered as (1a) and (1b). How to do that? Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: `\begin{subequations}` before the equations and `\end{subequations}` afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to reference equations using letters and numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494/5764)

Comment: \begin{subequations} and \end{subequations} are not working sir. It shows some error.

Comment: Did you load `amsmath`?