# Set the counter for multiple equations of the same kind

Tags: counters

I want equations (2) and (3) to be labeled as (1a) and (1b)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,table,usenames, dvipsnames]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{def}{RGB}{66,103,178}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
enhanced, colframe=blue!30!black,
colback=def!20, boxrule=1pt,
#1}

\begin{document}

Some text…
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=R^2
\end{empheq}

Some text…
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2+Ax+By+C z=0
\end{empheq}

Some text…
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is not clear at all. What would you like to have, precisely?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Bernard says it is not at all clear what you want to do. Further, can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: environment `subequations` from `asmath` package is your friend

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to reference equations using letters and numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/494/5764) (due to the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

see if the following  example gives what you looking for:

```
documentclass[12pt,a4paper,table,usenames, dvipsnames]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{def}{RGB}{66,103,178}
\usepackage{empheq}% it call `amsmath
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mymath}[1][]{%
nobeforeafter, math upper, tcbox raise base,
enhanced, colframe=blue!30!black,
colback=def!20, boxrule=1pt,
#1}

\begin{document}

Some text…
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:my equations}  % <---
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=R^2
\end{empheq}

Some text…
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2+Ax+By+C z=0
\end{empheq}

Some text…
\begin{empheq}[box={\mymath[colback=Bittersweet!20]}]{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations} % <---

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: @DimitriosSykias, than you can accept this answer with clicking on check mark at top left side of answer :-)